# Ninject, injecting Membership.Provider in RegisterServices of ninject initialization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject.web.mvc

Anybody know how to configure Membership.Provider in RegisterServices of ninject initialization code?

In my code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        // Put additional bindings here
        kernel.Bind<IDatabaseFactory>().To<DatabaseFactory>();
        kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
        kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<IRoleRepository>().To<RoleRepository>();
        kernel.Bind<ISecurityService>().To<SecurityService>();
        kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
        kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);
    }
```

all modules are binded with the exception of kernel.Inject lines. I'm receiving the error: "This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage".

The file is NinjectWebCommon of a standard nuget ninject.mvc installation.
I'm trying to create a custom membership provider and injecting the service layer (SecurityService) in the provider.

Any help?

Comment: Although this is a bit of a tangent from your question, this blog post (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/04/27/ProviderIsNotAPattern.aspx) from Mark Seemann (and the comments) has some interesting discussion about providers and dependency injection.

Comment: This is a duplicate, there is a better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412279/how-to-configure-ninject-for-mvc4-custom-membership-provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit my head against the wall with this same issue, I finally found a relatively clean solution [here](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2012/02/08/asp-net-provider-injection-with-ninject-3-0-0/).

The basic approach is:

1. Use `[Inject]` attribute on any dependency properties in your custom membership provider class.
2. Create a http module to resolve/inject your providers right away (Ninject 3 supports injecting HttpModules).
3. Replace those last 2 `inject` statements in your `RegisterServices()` method with bindings for the provider and new HttpModule.

   `kernel.Bind<MembershipProvider>().ToMethod(ctx => Membership.Provider);`
    `kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<ProviderInitializationHttpModule>();`

Comment: This works with Custom MemberShipProvider, but any ideas How to make this work with Custom RoleProvider as dependencies in Custom RoleProvider are not getting injected if I take the route you have mentioned.