# How to inject IUserRepository into custom membership provider using Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, custom-membershipprovider

I have DI set up in my project using Ninject. Here is an example for the UserController.

```
private readonly IRoleRepository roleRepository;
private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

public UserController(IUserRepository userRepository, IRoleRepository roleRepository)
{
    this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

In my NinjectWebCommon.cs file I have this:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IControllerFactory>().To<DefaultControllerFactory>();
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<PortalContext>().InSingletonScope();
    kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRoleRepository>().To<RoleRepositoroy>();
}
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to inject the user and role repositories into the custom membership provider. Any help is much appreciated as I have hit a wall here. I am using Asp.net MVC4 and EF4 with the repository and unit of work patterns. Thanks.

Comment: I struggled with this for a while, I found a solution and posted it to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053289/ninject-injecting-membership-provider-in-registerservices-of-ninject-initializa/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple solution you could just property inject them with Ninject.

```
[Inject]
public IUserRepository UserRepository {get;set;}
```

Comment: When I do that my UserRepository is always null?

Comment: @BBauer42 Sorry difficult to say without seeing what your code is this resolves for me.  Are you using public properties wont work otherwise.

Comment: @BBauer42 odd.  IS the provider in another project to your MVC application?

Comment: I add these two lines to the register services method: kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider); ...then I run again and get an error "This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage. "  ..I tried adding the two keys to the web config after looking at this thread and it didn't resolve the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626647/asp-net-this-method-cannot-be-called-during-the-applications-pre-start-initial

Comment: provider is in the same project

Comment: I was able to do this using DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>() in the membership's constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can use property injection

```
[Inject]
public IUserRepository userRepository {get;set;};
```

You will have to be careful regarding the scope of your DBContext though, as the MembershipProvider class is a singleton whose scope is the lifetime of the application.

Comment: When I do that my UserRepository is always null. I have not created a constructor in MyMembershipProvider. I also have nothing in RegisterServices related to the membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

@feanz, regarding your question:

@BBauer42 odd. IS the provider in another project to your MVC application?

What would you have to do different if the custom provider is in a separate project (class library)?