# How to configure Ninject for MVC4 & custom Membership provide?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject, custom-membershipprovider

According to this article description [custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/)

I implement the custom Membership provide with inject.

**Custom Membership provider**

```
using Ninject;

public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
        [Inject]
        public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }

[...]
```

**Custom Role Provider**

```
using Ninject;

public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
      [Inject]
      public IUserRoleRepository UserRoleRepository { get; set; }
[...]
```

within **Web.Config**

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomsMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomsMembershipProvider" type="namespace.CustomsMembershipProvider"/>
      </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="customRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="customRoleProvider" type="namespace.customRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Now within **NinjectWebCommon**

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
      var kernel = new StandardKernel();
      kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
      kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

      RegisterServices(kernel);
      return kernel;
}

private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
  [...]

  kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
  kernel.Bind<IUserRoleRepository>().To<UserRoleRepository>();

  // Inject user & role repository into our custom membership & role providers.
   kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
   kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);
}
```

when I run application I got error

> This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start
>   initialization stage.

from  `kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);` this line

But If I Kernel setting put within **Application_Start**

I got bellow Error

> Error activating IUserRepository No matching bindings are available,
>   and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path:   2) Injection of
>   dependency IUserRepository into property UserRepository of type
>   CustomMembershipProvider   1) Request for CustomeMembershipProvider

How to solve that. ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble trying this and ended up adding a method that gets me a repository

```
using System.Web.Mvc;  //Used to access dependency resolver

    private IUserRepository GetUserRepository()
    {
        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>();
    }
```

I then call this in the methods that require it

I was able to get the repository to become injected using constructor injection but as soon as I went to use the repository the object had been disposed.  I found the above to be the simplest alternative.

However, I guess you could also use the `Initialize()` method

```
    IUserRepository userRepository;
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);
        this.userRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>();
    }
```

Or another way would be to use a property

```
public IUserRepository UserRepository
{
    get
    {
        return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I put `Initialize()` method or `IUserRepository UserRepository` property. Now within controller `(IUserRepository userRepository)` , so any changes required to call from Controller ?

Comment: No, all of the above can be put in your membership provider.

Comment: So there is no `set;` for `IUserRepository UserRepository` property? only `[inject]IUserRepository UserRepository {get;}` within membership provider. Rest of the `Kernel.Inject` & kernel.bind<>` settings within **NinjaWebCommmon**  and configuration in **Web.Config** remain same ?

Comment: You need to remove the `[Inject]` attribute as we are no longer injecting it.  Instead we are now getting it from ninject when we need it. NinjectWebCommon and Web.config can remain unchanged

Comment: You can probably remove the bindings you are doing in `CreateKernel()`

Comment: `kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);  kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);`. So this is also not required within NinjectWebCommon ?  But basic binding such as `kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();` required ??

Comment: Correct.  You are not using ninject to inject your providers, only your repositories

Comment: One stupid question, is `DependencyResolver` is a part of the Ninija?

Comment: Not a stupid question.  `DependencyResolver` is part of `System.Web.Mvc` so add a using to you membership provider

Comment: Thanks, now let me try this.

Comment: Will you please help me regarding this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425236/how-to-call-custom-membership-provider-method-within-controller-with-ninject-rep)

Answer (score 8):

The result is always null. why? because asp.net has it's own static property for membership.

which is membership.provider. and this instance is not part of instance ninject management.

to workaround it , you need to use kernel.inject  . but on the generate aspnetmvc.cs you would see that it's injection on PreApplicationStart event and won't let you.

here is the soloution by **cipto** that solve the problem for me. add this to your NinjectWebCommon

```
    [assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TopRankFantasy.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")]
    [assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TopRankFantasy.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "RegisterMembership")]
    [assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(TopRankFantasy.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Stop")]

    public static void RegisterMembership()
    {
        bootstrapper.Kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
    }
```

Link to article: [Ninject and customMembership asp.net mvc 3](http://netindonesia.net/blogs/cipto/archive/2012/02/05/ninject-and-custommembership-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Comment: "Did you ever know that you're my hero,
and everything I would like to be?"  Thanks for saving my butt, this is the right way to do it with ninject and MVC

Answer (score 1):

Since a custom `RoleProvider` often comes along with the custom `MembershipProvider`, in that case it is useful to add an injection for the Role Provider class. I used the **ramon22's** solution with an additional line.

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TopRankFantasy.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TopRankFantasy.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "RegisterMembership")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(TopRankFantasy.App_Start.NinjectMVC3), "Stop")]

public static void RegisterMembership()
{
    bootstrapper.Kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
    bootstrapper.Kernel.Inject(Roles.Provider);
}
```