# Custom Membership provider & MVC 4

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, membership-provider

Continue from this solution : [How to configure Ninject for MVC4 & custom Membership provide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412279/how-to-configure-ninject-for-mvc4-custom-membership-provide)

I declare

```
public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<UserModel>
{
MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, ... , string providername = null);

void Logout();
Boolean Login(string userName, string Password, bool persistCookie = false);
bool RegisterUser(UserModel user);
}
```

And implement within **UserRepository**

```
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<MyDbContext, UserModel>, IUserRepository
{
        UserModel _user = null;

        public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext> unitOfWork)
            : base(unitOfWork)
{

}

   public MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, ... , string providername = null)
        {                
            using (UnitOfWork)
            {                   
                _user = new UserModel
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    RoleId = roleId
                    [other property set]
                };    
                Insert(_user);
                UnitOfWork.Commit();
             }
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;

                return new MembershipUser(providername, ...);
}

public bool RegisterUser(UserModel user)
{
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
        CreateUser(user.UserName, user.Password, user.Email, user.PasswordQuestion, user.PasswordAnswer, user.IsApproved, null, out createStatus, ...);

   if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
   {
                    return true;
   }
   else
   {                return false;
   }
}
[..]
```

Now within CustomMembership Provider

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
    {

        public IUserRepository UserRepository { get { return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserRepository>(); } }

    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, ...)
        {
            return UserRepository.CreateUser(username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer, isApproved, providerUserKey, out status, Membership.Provider.Name);
        }
[...]
```

Now within **Controller**

```
public AccountController(IAccountRepository accountRepository, IUserRepository userRepository, IUnitOfWork<MyDbContext> unitOfWork)
{
            _acountRepository = accountRepository;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}

public ActionResult Register(UserModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      _userRepository.RegisterUser(model);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

**1.** I got the Error Provider name is **Null** from UserRepository **CreateUser method** from this line   `return new MembershipUser(providername,...);`.

But I already pass it as `Membership.Provider.Name` within **customMembership** provider.

**2.** What is the proper way to call **Membershipprovider** method from **Controller** ?

**3.** Is the any other **Ninject** configuration required to call Membership provider method via **IUserRepository**, other that bellow ?

```
 kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
```

**4.** Web.config as [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412279/how-to-configure-ninject-for-mvc4-custom-membership-provide)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have CustomMembershipProvider.CreateUser and UserRepository.CreateUser.
Your controller is directly calling UserRepository.CreateUser but I think you really want to call CustomMembershipProvider.CreateUser?

Your Controller is calling

```
public bool RegisterUser(UserModel user)
{
    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
    CreateUser(user.UserName, user.Password, user.Email, user.PasswordQuestion, user.PasswordAnswer, user.IsApproved, null, out createStatus, ...);
```

which in turn is calling

```
public MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, ... , string providername = null)
```

but, as far as I can tell, you are passing a NULL for the provider name.

What you really want to split this up a bit more into a MembershipService which you can inject into your controllers.

I can't give you a simple "change this line" answer, the problem is conceptual, sorry. You *could* pass a hard-coded providername but then you really do start to violate everything.

Comment: I already inject `IUserRepository` into my Controller and configure it through `Ninject`. So anything else I have to configure.?

Comment: I *think* you meant to call CustomMembershipProvider.CreateUser. But you are *actually* calling  UserRepository.CreateUser directly without involving CustomMembershipProvider at all. And I guess that UserRepository *on its own* has no knowledge of Membership.Provider.Name.

Comment: I really wish I could give you a simple answer, but the problem is not syntax, it is conceptual. My best advice is, unfortunately, to go back to the drawing board and spend some more time reading up on the whole membership provider thing and how to make custom ones. It's a complicated subject and takes quite a lot of time to get to understand, sadly. Really sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

In Web.Config something like this.... You tell Membership provider with provider to use.
In this case your custom provider.
But im not sure why ninject plays a role in this concept, so cant help with that aspect sorry.
The customer provider MUST know its own name.  But hardly an Issue.
The Web.config has the name of the custom provider.  So config not hard coded.

```
 <membership defaultProvider="YourProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="5">
  <providers>
    <!--attribute names in camelCase version of .net class MembershipProvider Properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership_properties
    See BOS class for constants : BOSSysConst 
        type = Implmenting provider class  namespace.Classname 
    How to configure membership providers...    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t -->
    <add name="YourProvider" 
         type="YourNamespace.YourProvider"     
         connectionStringName="YourConnectionString"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         applicationName="IMPORTANT" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

The Controller calls the static class  for createUser    **Membership.CreateUser**
or **Membership.ValidateUser**  to logon.

For details on implmenting a custom provider see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
    // Sample calling the create user function  
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, passwordQuestion: null, passwordAnswer: null, isApproved: true, providerUserKey: null, status: out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, createPersistentCookie: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I use Dependency Injection (IOC) , that is why